# Referencing a button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm pretty new but I'm trying to reference a button from another. I disable the first button when I press it, but I want to enable it when I press the other button. Check this out. It doesn't like my second sender reference.

```
@IBAction func IBbtnUpdateTap(sender: UIButton){
  sender.enabled = false
}

@IBAction func addSpinsButton() {

    sender.enabled = true
}
```

Any ideas from you coding wizards?

Comment: do you have IBOutlets connected for the buttons in your viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the context of your function `addSpinsButton` as no sender variable. You must add a reference to your button in the class.

You can do this with something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

Link the button in interface builder (same way you have done with your function, but for the outlet)

Then your `addSpinsButton` will become:

```
@IBAction func addSpinsButton() {
    myButton.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

  @IBAction func button1Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.enabled = false
  }

  @IBAction func button2Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    button1.enabled = true
  }
}
```